# What Adventurers League rewards do players and DMs earn from "Rrakkma?"

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-adventurers-league

"[Rrakkma](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/ddia-mord)" is a short published adventure released together with *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*. It is branded as an Adventurers League module and is assigned adventure code DDIA-MORD. Players must use the supplied pregenerated 9th-level Githzerai and Githyanki characters to play this module.

With the current Adventurers League rules that were introduced with Season 8, do players and DMs earn Advancement and Treasure Checkpoints for playing "Rrakkma?" If they do, can they apply them to an AL character of their choice? Or perhaps just to a tier-2 AL character? Is the "Rrakkma" [story award](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/ddia-mord/appendices#ALRewards) still applicable under the new AL Season 8 rules?

The AL Content Catalog v8.4 only mentions that no magic items from "Rrakkma" may ever be unlocked for purchase. The AL Player's Guide v8.2 and DM's Guide v8.2 do not mention "Rrakkma" at all.

The author of the [Adventurers League Rewards spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1omoTExpdh7cdiq9NnfVpf6-CnAkGRbA-FMIiNaZXpvg/edit?usp=sharing) appears to believe that Rrakkma provides 4 to 8 ACP and TCP. But it provides no guidance on which characters those checkpoints can be applied to.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Not A Normal Module

While it has an adventure code (DDIA-MORD) that makes it look like a traditional DDAL introductory module, Rrakkma doesn't fit into the normal mold of DDAL content. It is specifically designed to be run with the pregenerated characters, and normal DDAL characters cannot officially participate in it.

### Players & DMs Get A Critter Certificate

The [Wrap Up](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/adventures/ddia-mord/the-far-realm#WrapUp) section (page 17 in the PDF version of the module) details the rewards:

> Since this adventure MUST be played with the pregenerated characters provided, rewards are treated a bit differently. For playing in this event, each player and their Dungeon Master receive the event certificate, CHAOS CURIO.
>
> The players may not keep magic items found listed below; [...]

That's it... just the certificate, which can be applied to a single DDAL character of the player's choice. The cert allows the character to have one of two companion creatures - *Grahkkim the Star Spawn Kitten* or *T'k'shk the Diminutive Eidolon*. They're purely aesthetic/trinket companions - they have no combat ability and are not usable as familiars.

## No Checkpoints

Under [Season 8](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack) rules, DMs receive the same number of checkpoints that they awarded to players. DDIA-MORD uses pregenerated characters and doesn't award any checkpoints, so the DM doesn't get anything either. This is not a change from prior seasons, as it had no award instructions there, either.

## No Unlocks

The Season 8 [DDAL Player & DM Pack](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Player--DM-Pack) specifically calls out DDIA-MORD as never unlocking any magic items, not even for Dungeon Masters.

## TLDR

DDIA-MORD is strictly an introductory module for *Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes*. It does not provide anything of mechanical substance to a player or DM.